# Match User Preference to Object Attributes Order By Match Percentage

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, matching

I'm trying to calculate how closely an item matches a user's defined preferences. The following is how I thought of doing it. But I'm not overly experienced and wanted to know if there might be a better way to go about it.

Using cars as a simple example. We will narrow it down to color and style of car (car, van, etc.).

---

**Part One**

The user selects in an HTML form the following:

```
Color: ( )White, (*)Black, ( )Red
Style: ( )Car, ( )Van, (*)Suv, (*)Truck
```

Now if I convert the above into a binary number where the **first digit = first attribute** (white) and continues on.

**Attribute Code** = 0100011 (black, suv, truck)

---

**Part Two**

Now with MySQL

```
Select item_id, attribute_code FROM items

items table = [item_id][attribute_code]
```

Next use PHP to calculate how closely each items attribute code matches the users preferences.

```
// Set users attribute code to var
$user_pref = $_POST['user_att_code'];

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    // Pull attribute_code from database and put into var
    $item_code = $row['attribute_code'];

    // Set counters
    $count_digit = 0;
    $count_match = 0;

    // Length of attribute code
    $length = 7;

    // Start calculating match
    while($count_digit <= $length)
    {
        // Does first digit of users code = 1?
        // Does first digit of items code = 1?
        if($user_pref{$count_digit} != 0 && $user_pref{$count_digit} == $item_code{$count_digit})
        {
            // Add a positive match point to counter
            $count_match++;
        }

        // Next digit in code
        $count_digit++;
    }

    if($count_match > 0)
    {
    // Make array of item_id and match amount
    $item_search [$row['item_id']] = $count_match;
    }   
}

// Sort array by most similar
arsort($item_search);
```

Then a little more code is used to calculate a percentage.

The above did the following: It took the users desired attribute code and compared it to every items attribute code in the database. It went digit by digit through each code and made a tally every time there was a match. At the end it put the tally for that item into an array and went onto the next item's attribute code.

```
user: 0100011
it_1: 0100011 = 100% match
it_2: 0100100 = 50% match
it_3: 0011000 = 0% match
// If you notice the 50% does not make sense ignore it.
// I left something out for simplification.
```

Now I know this works. However, it does not seem like a good way to go about it. **Performance** wise mostly. Assuming over **150,000 items, and an attribute code length of about 200**. That's at least 30,000,000 calculations for one search (based on above).

Is there another way perhaps? Is this a big deal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve better perfomance you should reorganise your system.

Use separated tables for Colors and Styles. Also tables to organize relations between data (Items - Colors, Items - Styles).

You will be able to select from database ONLY parameters user has selected and not to iterate over all Items each request.